# Resize every image to the same size

Tags: imagemagick

I need to resize any given image to 1200x700px without distorting it, no matter if the image is smaller or bigger. its okay when something gets cropped.

is it possible to do this in a simple way or do i need a lot of if/else to get there?

what's the best approach using imagemagick (command-line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
convert image.suffix -resize "1200x700^" -gravity center -extent 1200x700 result.suffix
```

Comment: Wow... so easy! Thank you @fmw42

Comment: @fx123 Better to formally accept the answer (other people see it accepted), by clicking the check mark under the votes on the answer.

Comment: Done.. thanks for the info